# Have sound play when alert is triggered

Tags: javascript

So I have in my javascript an if statement.  When it returns true it opens an alert box and plays an alarm sound.  The problem is that the sound doesn't play until I hit the ok button.

Here is the relevant information:

```
  if (x > 10) {
        var snd = new Audio('/alarm.mp3');
        snd.play();
        alert("Thank you!");
    }
```

Ideally I want the sound which is around 6 seconds long to play until it is at the end or until the user hits closes out of the dialog.  But really getting the alarm to sound before closing the alert box would be good enough.

Comment: because alert is a blocking call, nothing executes while it is open, you should use an html modal box, http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

Comment: Just a hunch: whill the sound play if you delay the alert, like `setTimeout(function() {alert("Thank you!")}, 500)` ?

Comment: The one thing I like about the alert as opposed to a modal is that the browser will go to the page with the alert when you are in a different tab.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Preload your audio file in the html beforehand like :

```
<audio id="xyz" src="whatever_you_want.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

if(x > 10)
{
    document.getElementById('xyz').play();
    alert("Thank you!");
}
```

This should surely work.

Comment: Anyway to end the audio early if a user hits close on the alert?

Comment: Its a bad practice to perform anything on "Alert Okay" click still you can try something like :
`function myFunction()`
`{`
`var r = alert("You pressed a button!");`
`if (r==true)`
`{`
`}`
`else`
`{`
`document.getElementById('xyz').stop();`
`..OR..`
`document.getElementById('xyz').controls.stop();`
`}`

Answer (score 8):

For a quick and dirty beep, you could use [this "beep" MP3](https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190531135120/beep.mp3). It's awful.

Here's a working example:

```
var mp3_url = 'https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190531135120/beep.mp3';

(new Audio(mp3_url)).play()
```

If you want to make it extra extra annoying (I needed a psuedo-pager to alert myself when an appointment slot opened up), just repeat the beep every second:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(){(new Audio(mp3)).play()}, i * 1000)
}
```

It's truly horrendous, worse that marquee text! You are a bad person if you put that "repeated beep" code snippet in a real web page. Worked great as a hacky pager though.

Comment: At the bottom example `mp3` should be `mp3_url` (couldn't edit since it's less than 6 characters)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
var snd = new Audio('/alarm.mp3');    
snd .onended = function () { alert("Thank you!"); };
snd .play();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

```
if (x > 10) {
        var snd = new Audio('/alarm.mp3');
        snd.play();
        setTimeout(function(){alert("Thank you!")},6000);
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if I reset x to do another alarm the second time the alert doesn't work because of the setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

Why not leverage the HTML5 audio events.

The event ended is triggred once the audio ends playing

```
snd.addEventListener('ended', showAlert);

function showAlert() {
 alert("YOUR MESSAGE");
}
```