# Javascript how to custom Notification sound

Tags: javascript, notifications

I'm using [web API Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification). I find there's no sound when using chrome, but firefox has its own default alert sound. So, problem comes: I want to custom the alert sound. Does anyone know how to specify the sound, or how to forbidden the default sound of Firefox?

```
var notification = Notification("TestTittle");
```

For more details, http://jsfiddle.net/43CrR/

Comment: show some code pls..!

Comment: @Sudhir the code is quite simple. just one line. I'll re-edit my question.

Comment: @Sudhir you can see more details by opening the url that I just added.

Comment: You can play your own sound for an alert, see this for an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815323/have-sound-play-when-alert-is-triggered)

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like:

add audio tag as:

```
<audio id='notif_sound'>
    <source src='alarm.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' />
    <source src='alarm.ogg' type='audio/ogg' />
    <source src='alarm.wav' type='audio/wav' />
</audio>
```

and js code::

```
if (window.webkitNotifications && window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() == 0) {
    var message = 'some message here';
    var notif = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification('', 'Notification', message );

    //attach sound play on 'show' event of notification
    notif.addEventListener("show", function() {
        document.getElementById('notif_sound').play();
    }, false);
    //show the notification
    notif.show();
}
```

Comment: But how to disable the default alert sound of firefox?