# Adding sound to javascript to play when word entered is correct

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am making a basic html and javascript app where the user has to enter words into blank spaces and press a submit button. 
If all the words are correct, I want some audio to play and an alert to pop up to say congratulations. If they are incorrect, I want the audio to play and the alert to say sorry.

However, no matter what I try, the alert always pops up and the sound doesnt play until it goes. Is there a way to get the sound to play before the alert comes up?

HTML:

```
<pre id="poem">
<b><u>Social Media</b></u></br>
Relax yourself,
As I <span id = "word1" contenteditable>______</span>
through your mind
Scroll down the pages
of your spine
Reading every word 
and thought on
your <span id = "word2" contenteditable>____</span> like a <span id = "word3" contenteditable>____</span>
Stumbled Upon 
you then <span id = "word4" contenteditable>_______</span> onto
your looks--IGuess
I'm <span id = "word5" contenteditable>______</span> into you
You're my one
and only <span id = "word6" contenteditable>________</span>

Will you <span id = "word7" contenteditable>______</span> me?
</pre>

<button id = "submit" onclick = "isCorrect()"> submit </button>
```

JS:

```
function isCorrect(){
    var word1 = document.getElementById("word1");
    var word2 = document.getElementById("word2");
    var word3 = document.getElementById("word3");
    var word4 = document.getElementById("word4");
    var word5 = document.getElementById("word5");
    var word6 = document.getElementById("word6");
    var word7 = document.getElementById("word7");
    var audio = new Audio('sound_files/success.mp3');

    font(word1, word2, word3, word4, word5, word6, word7);


    if (word1.innerHTML == "digg" && word2.innerHTML == "face" && word3.innerHTML == "book" && word4.innerHTML == "tumbled" && word5.innerHTML == "linked" && word6.innerHTML == "interest" && word7.innerHTML == "follow")
    {
        audio.play();
        alert("Congratulations! You got all of the words right.");
    }
    else
    {
        audio.play();
        alert("Sorry! Please check the red coloured words as these are still incorrect. Also make sure you have entered words into all of the spaces.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, do not use an alert. :)  Plenty of open source libraries that use CSS to show messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have sound play when alert is triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815323/have-sound-play-when-alert-is-triggered)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like that (that's what i was using a while ago)

```
<!-- HTML -->
<audio id="music" src="mymusic.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>


//Javascript
if (word1.innerHTML == "digg" && word2.innerHTML == "face" && word3.innerHTML == "book" && word4.innerHTML == "tumbled" && word5.innerHTML == "linked" && word6.innerHTML == "interest" && word7.innerHTML == "follow")
{
    document.getElementById('music').play();
    alert("Congratulations! You got all of the words right.");
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('music').play();
    alert("Sorry! Please check the red coloured words as these are still incorrect. Also make sure you have entered words into all of the spaces.");
}
```

And as said in the comments, you may want to check out some libraries, some of them could help you with this.

Comment: Yeah i am just beginning to learn and they seemed complicated haha but thanks a million for this it works!

Comment: They are worth the time you'll put in learning how to use them, goodluck :)